# Android ImageButton image scaling

Tags: android, imagebutton, scaling

I have two ImageButtons in a LinearLayout. The Facebook image is 320x113 and the Google+ image is 325x113 (same height). I want both images to display with an equal height (and the wider image will show wider). But for some reason when displaying, the Google+ button is scaling the size larger. Why? Why I ask you!

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_large">

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnFBShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/fb_share"
            android:contentDescription="Share on Facebook"
            />

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnGPShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/gp_share"
            android:contentDescription="Share on Google+" />

        <!--  
            android:layout_weight="1" -->

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Are the two images in different drawable-?dpi folder?

Comment: If nothing works, you could change it to a `RelativeLayout` and use the `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom` to force the Google+ button to align with the Facebook buttons' top and bottom.

Comment: image size are different check width and height of the images(W*H).

Comment: BrainCrash, they are in the same folder.

Comment: sri, the image sizes are different but they are the same height. So they should render as the same height (ideally)

Comment: BrainCrash, your comment pushed me to try something. The images were in the same folder but I decided to delete images from all other folders and tried again. This time I got two wildly different sizes. So I cleaned the project and whala! They are now correct. You only commented and didnt answer the question so I dont know how to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had something to due with Eclipse caching the image files. The cached versions were not the same size. Cleaning the project forced Eclipse to use the newer (same sized files) from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....

*weight_sum is total weight for the LinearLayout and Layout_weight is applicable to the child views of LL.
sum of weight of child views will be equal to weight_sum specified in LL tag.
In bellow  two ImageButtons have same weight and sum is equal to total,So two child views will share the total width equally*

new snippet

```
<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFBShare"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/fb_share"
        android:contentDescription="Share on Facebook"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGPShare"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gp_share"
        android:contentDescription="Share on Google+"  />
</LinearLayout>
```